# np.savetxt not writing entire array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using np.savetxt to write a 3d array into a single csv file.  the first index stores all 3 columns and all 131 rows.  Then I use a loop to append the other indexes to the bottom of the csv, but the last 23 columns are cut off.

spars is the 3d array and each of the spar 1-8 are (131,3) arrays

```
spars = np.array((spar1,spar2,spar3,spar4,spar5,spar6,spar7,spar8))

file_out = 'spars.csv'
np.savetxt(file_out,spars[0],delimiter=',')  
for i in range(1,8):
    f = open((file_out),'a')
    f.write('\n')
    np.savetxt(f,spars[i],delimiter=',')    
    f.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting the whole write in a `with` context?

```
spars = [spar1,spar2,spar3,spar4,spar5,spar6,spar7,spar8]
# alist would be just as good as array for this iteration
file_out = 'spars.csv'
with open(file_out, 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,spars[0],delimiter=',')
    for arr in spars[1:]:
        f.write('\n')
        np.savetxt(f, arr, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

for some reason, because it is not closing before reopening, the last 23 elements must be getting cut off,  maybe the next loop starts writing in before it has time to finish?

f.close()

(with the parentheses)   fixed the issue.

Comment: I would suggest not opening and closing the same file multiple times. Let python handle file buffering and flushing to disk by only opening and closing once. For this, using the `with open(blah_blah_blah) as f:` construct is quite convenient.